# Learning roadmap for geometric topology

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

What books one must read and in what sequence to learn a low-dimensional topology at the grad level? The goal is to read in about  a year at least something about Geometrization conjecture of Thurston. The background of the OP is merely Basic Topology by MA Armstrong and undergrad level abstract algebra.
Please suggest a roadmap. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure about the roadmap, but you should download http://blms.oxfordjournals.org/content/15/5/401.full.pdf+html

Comment: @MarkGrant, I do not have access to that particular document.

Comment: It's Scott's survey on $3$-manifolds, also available here http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~pscott/

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/93408/reference-on-geometric-topology . See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128962/reference-on-geometric-topology

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the best introductions to the subject is certainly Thurston's [Three-dimensional Topology and Geometry, Vol.1](http://books.google.de/books?id=9kkuP3lsEFQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Three-Dimensional+Geometry+and+Topology&hl=de&sa=X&ei=rml1UdjXH5SE0QHSs4GQBw&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Three-Dimensional%2520Geometry%2520and%2520Topology&f=false) (not to be confused with his much harder lecture notes *Three-dimensional Topology and Geometry*). It has almost no prerequisits, but leads you right to the statement of the geometrization conjecture of Thurston and some surrounding mathematics.

A more topological view on 3-manifolds is presented in a set of notes by Hatcher: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/3M/3Mfds.pdf

For mapping class groups, i.e. groups of homeomorphisms of surfaces, you may have a look at Farb's and Margalit's http://www.math.ethz.ch/~bgabi/Farb%20Magalit%20January%202011%20version.pdf . This is not directly related to the Geometrization Conjecture, but mapping class groups are extremely important both in 2-dimensional and 3-dimensional geometry.

Edit: At some point you have also to learn some differential topology to understand geometric topology. I myself learned differential topology (partly) from the book by Bröcker and Jänich, but this is a little bit terse - there might be better choices. But the nice thing is that Thurston's book does not really presuppose any deeper knowledge in differential topology.

I want also to comment than none of the above sources says anything about the proof of the geometrization conjecture; but I think, it would be unreasonable to try to understand the proof with your current background anyhow.

Comment: A gentler introduction than the Thurston book is the new Bonahon book: Low-Dimensional Geometry: From Euclidean Surfaces to Hyperbolic Knots

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I shall have my hands full with the references provided.

Comment: But will my question get deleted? 

Comment: It is true that the Thurston book is sometimes a bit tough for people which do not have a brilliant geometric intuition; but on the other hand, it also really helps to build geometric intuition. 